# Google Drive REST API v3, Resumable Upload: The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable

Tags: curl, google-api, google-drive-api

PREFACE: Other questions are similar, however I believe this is a different problem.

I'm trying to update a file in Google Drive with the REST API v3 in JavaScript using XHR, and I'm getting the error `The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable.`.
To avoid the need to debug the code, I'll simply past the actual cURL request that gets made (I've taken out any security related bits and replaced them with [WHAT_THE_ITEM_IS]):

```
curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/[FILE_ID]?uploadType=resumable&upload_id=[UPLOAD_ID]' -X PUT -H 'origin: http://[DOMAIN]' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'x-upload-content-type: application/json' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'content-range: bytes 0-26/27' -H 'referer: http://booklets-dev.resist.design:3000/' -H 'authority: www.googleapis.com' -H 'x-client-data: [CLIENT_DATA]' --data-binary $'{\n  "pages": [\n    []\n  ]\n}' --compressed
```

NOTE: The file to be uploaded/updated IS a JSON file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, stupid but simple answer here, you DO NOT want to add the `id` to the metadata when making the initial request to get the `upload_id`.

Meaning the problem has nothing to do with the upload request and everything to do with the request to `PATCH https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files/[FILE_ID]?uploadType=resumable` that is made to get the `Location` header you need to actually do the upload. See this page: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/resumable-upload